# Add two conditions in filter Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, conditional-statements

Im trying to add two conditions in filter but only one works. The first condition check if it has empty spaces between words and the second condition if words.length is bigger than the given minimum length.
 if the string is `"hello    world"` then i need to get when i split it `["hello", "world"]`. Instead of that I am getting `["hello", "", "", "", "world"]`

```
let wordsLength = sumOfSentence.split(" ");    
let longWords = wordsLength.filter(function(sumOfWord){
    //check if the words length is bigger than the minimum length
    //check if it has extra empty spaces
    if(sumOfWord !== "") return sumOfWord.length >= minLength
});
```

Comment: Use `&&` or `||` between the conditions, depending on whether you require both to be true or either to be true.

Comment: @Barmar I need both but when i add && the first condition doesnt work

Comment: "Im trying to add two conditions in filter" what filter? I'm confused as to what you are trying to achieve/need help with... Perhaps provide a more complete example?

Comment: I don't see the need to test both conditions. If `sumOfWord` is an empty string, its length will always be greater than `minLength` (unless `minLength` is `0`).

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Your code works: http://rextester.com/BWYXI27367

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to filter if sumOfWord is not empty and its length is greater than minLength. @Barmar suggests you the good solution, use the following code.

```
let wordsLength = sumOfSentence.split(" ");    
let longWords = wordsLength.filter(function(sumOfWord){
    return ((sumOfWord.trim() != '') && sumOfWord.length >= minLength)
});
```