# Use array filter with both conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to apply two conditions into an `array filter`.

Actually, I have this code:

```
arr = arr.filter(
    a => a.color != $(this).data('color'),
    b => b.name != $(this).data('name')
);
```

How can I specify that I need to filter the color AND the name?

Comment: Use `&&` condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add two conditions in filter Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083735/add-two-conditions-in-filter-javascript) and [Filter array of objects by multiple properties and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330952) and [How to use filter array of objects by 2 conditions with an arrow function in js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761482) and [Filter with two arguments\parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411296)

Answer (score 0):

Use && operator to check both conditions

```js
let arr = [
{color: 'blue', name: 'sky'},
{color: 'red', name: 'foo'},
{color: 'yellow', name: 'submarine'},
{color: 'red', name: 'velvet'}
];

arr = arr.filter(a => a.color !== $('#example').data('color') && a.name !== $('#example1').data('name'));

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" data-name="sky" data-color="blue">
</div>
```

Comment: So I need to use `a.color` and `a.name` and not `b.name`? Why?

Comment: because a is the parameter of the callback which represents the individual element of the array and not b

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little utility for combining predicates:

```
const pred = (() => {
  const and = p1 => p2 => x => p1(x) && p2(x)
  const or = p1 => p2 => x => p1(x) || p2(x)

  return { and, or }
})()

// ...

const isntSomeColor = a => a.color != $(this).data('color')
const isntSomeName = b => b.name != $(this).data('name')

const result = input.filter(pred.and(isntSomeColor)(isntSomeName))
```

In general both boolean conjunction and disjunction form monoids, and monoid returning functions also form monoids. So if you're using some functional programming library you could also do:

```
const preds = [
  a => a.color != $(this).data('color'),
  b => b.name != $(this).data('name')
]

const result = input.filter(arr.fold(fn(and))(preds))
```